# Getting nested values regardless of the value mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, flask, pymongo

How can I get the value of the field regardless of the value?

My query is

```
receiver = {'_id' : requests['id']}
match = {'matches.id' : requests['match']}
queryrec = user_col.find_one(receiver, match)
```

This is the output:

```
{
  "_id": 2,
  "matches": [
    {
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

However what I want is to fetch the UUID if the "id" is found. Inside the matches regardless of the value.

Here is the sample of matches array in mongoDB:

```
"matches": [
    {
      "id": 3
      "UUID": A123F-ASD1234-ASD123
    }
```

Is there any way I can do it in pymongo?

Comment: Your match is the projection parameter of your query - is that what you want? If so, you can add the `UUID` to the projection. Have you tried something like `match = {'matches.id' : requests['match'], 'matches.uuid': 1}`

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere you should put this as an answer. Your comment worked like a magic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match is the projection parameter of your query - is that what you want?

If so, you can add the UUID to the projection.

Have you tried something like `match = {'matches.id' : requests['match'], 'matches.uuid': 1}`